# Can a low current device be damaged by a high current device when in parallel?

Tags: current, components, parallel, high-current, damage

Well, the title of this question tells it all, but repeat it here:

"Can a low current device be damaged by a high current device when in parallel?"

Came along this article:
http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4423709/Protecting-your-low-voltage-electronic-devices-from-electrical-overstress

For example, when you have a bluetooth module that consumes only 80mA and an amplifier that can consume a max of 2A, is it possible that the bluetooth module will be damaged by high current peaks on the powerrail (on the long term)?

If so, what is the easiest way to do to avoid this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mostly no.

You can construct a pathological case where there are issues: remember that the power rails have non-zero resistance and inductance. If the inductance was high, then sudden changes in current draw from the amplifier, and thus through the power rails could result in large voltage swings.

But this is why we decouple the power supply with capacitors, among other reasons.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. So in rare occasions it could be possible like you explained.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm putting Arduino analog inputs to monitor the voltage of cells connected in series to produce 36V/200A (for welding) so I guess this would be one of the not-so-mostly cases. I'm kind of learning electronics the same way I learned coding - learning by solving real-world problems (only with more magic smoke). Next stop: google "decouple power supply"!